# How do I hide or show adapters/views using cwac-merge?

Tags: android, android-adapter, commonsware-cwac

I have a fragment holding several lists, as you may guess the scrolling is a mess, so I give it a try to the [cwac-merge](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) adapter, it seems to do it's job fine, but I wanted to customize some of the items, i.e. I need some of the adapters to show or hide depending on how many items they have, right now empty list adapters are showing a blank space, and I would like to make them gone until items are retrieved.

[image]

On the screenshot (please excuse its blurred but Im not allowed to show the product yet) you can see I highlighted with red rectangles the empty spaces, where I'm setting the view to have Visibility = GONE.

Also one of these empty spaces is caused because an adapter has no items.

Is there a way to hide or show certain adapters or views inside the MergeAdapter so they don't occupy space?

Thanks

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! StackOverflow is for programming questions, and you have not asked a question. You also have no code,  no layouts, no screenshots illustrating your "blank space", etc. Hence, nobody is likely to be able to assist you.

Comment: @CommonsWare sorry, is it better now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where I'm setting the view to have Visibility = GONE

IIRC, having a `GONE` row in a `ListView` is problematic in general. `MergeAdapter` should not have an impact on it.

> Also one of these empty spaces is caused because an adapter has no items.

I rather doubt that. Hierarchy View should show you what is really going on.

> Is there a way to hide or show certain adapters or views inside the MergeAdapter so they don't occupy space?

An adapter returning `0` from `getCount()` should occupy no space, if you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `MergeAdapter` so that it can tell the `ListView` to redraw itself.

Comment: so there is no way to hide a view that has been added to the MergeAdapter?

Comment: @AldoReyes: I have no idea. I have never tried it, and I am skeptical that it is a good idea in the first place. If the structure of your `ListView` is changing so dramatically, set a new adapter set up the way you want. Or, switch to `ExpandableListView` (and cook up a suitable adapter for it), as `ExpandableListView` has the built-in notion of hiding and showing sections of its contents.

Comment: thank you mate, I decided to go back at having several list views, and setting the height depending on the number of items, I know it's not the best but these list wont grow to more than 5 items each. I'll mark you as the correct answer since it lead me to make this choice.